# How to find medical words from a sentence using python?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, data-science

I have many sentences and I want to find out the symptoms and disease from the sentence.

**For example:**

**Sentence:** I feel stomach pain but no coughing today. may be Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm

**output:**

- *symptoms*: stomach pain , coughing
- *disease*: Abdominal Aortic Aneurysm

Answer (score -1):

You can make a list of words from your sentences by using .split(" ") method, and then search your keywords in this list.